# WiFi/networking weirdness

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Ok, this is just bizarre.

I have a single wifi access point in my house. My main computer, running Win7 Ultimate x64, can't seem to get to anywhere on the internet. I can ping my router, I can access my printer's setup web page, but I can't access the router's administration page.

A Windows Virtual PC VM (running Win 7 Ultimate x86) on this same physical machine, can get to the internet just fine. It can't get to my router's administration page, but it gets everywhere else ok.

Do I have goblins?

Comment: Ended up completely resetting the router to factory settings, turning off DHCP, setting up everything by hand. Seems to be working...for now. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up eventually buying a new router. I chalk this one up to the oddities of the Linksys WRT110. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Gateway is wrong/missing in the x64 version?
You could do ipconfig /all on both versions.

Regarding the router's administration page, perhaps it is set to not allow administration by wireless - try a direct connection by wire.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the internet gateway IP is wrong.  I do this on purpose sometimes (as well as by accident :-)